# SQL INNER JOIN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have 3 tables (user, item, userlike) and 2 sql queries. How can I unify these two queries?

```
SELECT item.userid, item.id, user.name FROM item 
INNER JOIN user ON item.userid = user.id 

SELECT userid,itemid, COUNT(*) AS `liked` FROM userlike
WHERE userid=9
GROUP BY itemid
```

I want to know whether a specific user (9) has liked the item or not.

Result should be somthing like this

```
itemid userid name liked* (*whether 'user 9' liked this item or not)
1      7      foo  0
2      4      asd  1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `OUTER JOIN` for this

```
SELECT i.id itemid, u.id userid, u.name, COALESCE(liked, 0) liked
  FROM item i JOIN user u
    ON i.userid = u.id LEFT  JOIN 
(
  SELECT itemid, COUNT(*) liked 
    FROM userlike 
   WHERE userid = 9
   GROUP BY itemid
) l
    ON i.id = l.itemid;
```

or

```
SELECT i.id itemid, u.id userid, u.name, l.userid IS NOT NULL liked
  FROM item i JOIN user u
    ON i.userid = u.id LEFT  JOIN userlike l
    ON i.id = l.itemid
   AND l.userid = 9;
```

Sample output:

```
| ITEMID | USERID |  NAME | LIKED |
|--------|--------|-------|-------|
|      2 |      4 | user4 |     1 |
|      1 |      7 | user7 |     0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac755/16)** demo

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Thanks for the input. I believe that items do have names, though. But you right looking at OP's query it seems that it's user's name is expected in the resultset.

Comment: Thank you @peterm, your answer is what I want. P.S: my user table has a column 'name'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.id, item.userid, user.name, userlike.liked
FROM item
JOIN user ON user.id = item.userid
JOIN userlike ON item.id = userlike.itemid
WHERE userlike.liked = 1
GROUP BY item.id
```

**OR**

```
SELECT item.id, item.userid, user.name, userlike.liked
FROM item
JOIN user ON user.id = item.userid
JOIN userlike ON item.id = userlike.itemid
WHERE COUNT(userlike.liked) >= 1
GROUP BY item.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `COUNT`. You just need to know if there is an entry for a specific item and a specific user in the `userlike` table :

```
SELECT i.id as itemid, u.id as userid, u.name,
       case when ul.userid is null then 0 else 1 end as liked
FROM item i
INNER JOIN user u ON i.userid = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN userlike ul ON i.id = ul.itemid AND ul.userid=9
ORDER BY i.id
```